# What address regions are protected/forbidden by the linux kernel?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, elf

I'm experimenting with the ELF file format, and I haven't yet figured out the pattern here. Here is a minimal ELF file:

```
$ cat zero.asm
.text
   .global _start
_start:
    movl    $0,%ebx         # first argument: exit code.
    movl    $1,%eax         # system call number (sys_exit).
    int     $0x80           # call kernel.

$ as zero.asm -o zero.o && ld zero.o -s && readelf -h -l a.out
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  ...
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  ...
  Entry point address:               0x400078

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000084 0x0000000000000084  R E    0x200000
```

There is only one load region, which is loaded into  LMA = VMA = `0x400000` with alignment `0x200000`. I'm not sure why `0x200000` is the default or how to change it in ld, but with some hex editing I can decrease the alignment to its minimum value `0x1000` (according to the ELF spec), and then I can also decrease the page load address. By experimentation, if I have it set to `.text = 0x10000` or above then it loads and runs successfully, and if I try to load it less than this then the program segfaults. Where is this number coming from? I checked `/proc/ID/maps` and I don't see any evidence of a protected page at 0-0x10000, but I know that this is where the kernel stores its interrupt handler stuff... but the whole process is in virtual memory anyway so it can't see kernel memory... what going on here? How does the kernel determine which address regions are accessible to my process?

Comment: Maybe not a coincidence that 2MiB is the x86-64 hugepage size.  (A whole page-directory of 4k pages).  Aligning to 2M boundaries can help transparent hugepages do a better job.  Also related: [Why can't I mmap(MAP\_FIXED) the highest virtual page in a 32-bit Linux process on a 64-bit kernel?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47712502)

Comment: The first kilobytes are commonly reserved to catch NULL pointer dereferences. Why 64KB? It needs to be a multiple of the page size (AFAIR, MIPS CPUs can have 64KB pages). And it shouldn't be too small (C structs can be quite large, so, if you have a NULL pointer to a structure, you want to cover struct sizes up to something reasonable).

Comment: Oh, I think this is relevant: `cat /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` returns `65536 = 0x10000`

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That's the relevant control variable.  You can set it all the way down to 0 if you want to map address 0.